# Is there any package for Apache, PHP and MariaDB similar to XAMPP?

Tags: php, mariadb

I was trying to search, if there is any package available similar to XAMPP to run PHP+MariaDB applications. It may be very simple question and not worth asking on StackOverflow, but I tried a lot and failed. It would be a great help if somebody can help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MariaDB is a drop in replacement for MySQL, so couldn't you easily use XAMPP and just install MariaDB to replace MySQL?